# Spring-Security Spotify API.Trying to redirect from authorization page results in 'localhost redirected you too many times.'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm having trouble authorizing my account with the Spotify API. When I try redirect from the Spotify authorization page to my `localhost:9090/home` the browser tells me I've been redirected too many times. I imagine the problem is that it doesn't recognise/know that I've just logged in and when trying to access a page that requires authorization I am rejected and get stuck in a redirect loop.

`ApplicationSecurity.java`

```
package com.programmer.gate;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .antMatcher("/**")
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/callback", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**","/oauth/token")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**","/callback","/home/**").authenticated()
          .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }

}
```

`HomeController.java`

```
package com.programmer.gate;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(auth.getPrincipal());
        return "/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String callback(@RequestParam(value = "code") String code, @RequestParam(value = "state") String state) {
        System.out.println("redirecting to home page");
        System.out.println("CODE: " + code);
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(auth.getDetails());
        return "/home";
    }

}
```

`application.properties`

```
server.port=9090
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

security.oauth2.client.clientId=<CLIENT_ID>
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=<CLIENT_SECRET>
security.oauth2.client.preEstablishedRedirectUri=http://localhost:9090/home
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
security.oauth2.client.tokenName=oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme=query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
security.oauth2.client.scope=playlist-read-private
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/me
security.oauth2.client.useCurrentUri=false
```

Is there anything that can be changed here which can allow the back-end to recognize that I'm not an 'anonymoususer'?

Comment: 'HomeController.calback' method intercepts '/home' path and returns '/home'. This is the cause. If you change return "/home"; to return "/something_else"; it should solve the problem

Comment: @eparvan I tried creating a separate 'test' endpoint to see if that would work but I'm still getting the same issue. Also the '/home' endpoint is never hit so I don't think that the issue is that it is returning '/home'